# Calculating the double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

> I have the following integral $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{xdxdy}{x^2 + y^2} $$

I first took the partial integral with respect to y to obtain the following:
$$ \left [ \frac{1}{x} \tan^{-1}x \frac{y}{x} \right ]_{y = 0}^{y = 1} \rightarrow \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \tan^{-1}x \, dx \ \text{(now taking partial integral with respect to x)} $$
I try u substitution next but I get stuck.

Also is $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{xdydx}{x^2 + y^2} = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{xdxdy}{x^2 + y^2} ?$$ by Fubuni's Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial integration yields $$\int_{y=0}^{y=1}\frac{x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}=x\int_{y=0}^{y=1}\frac{dy}{x^2+y^2}=x\left[\frac{1}{x}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right]_{y=0}^{y=1}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Your primitive is wrong. The correct one is
$$
\int \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\,dy=\arctan(y/x)+C.
$$
This means that you end up calculating
$$
\int_0^1\arctan(1/x)\,dx,
$$
which is doable.

I first did not see your second question. Yes, you can switch order here. I suggest that you try to do the problem integrating in that order once you are done with the first way. It is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\,dy=x\int\frac{1}{x^2++y^2}\,dy=\frac{1}{x}\int\frac{1}{\frac{y^2}{x^2}+1}\,dy$$

Then let $t:=\frac yx$.

Now that you got your primitive correctly you can procceed.